# "file is not gofmted" in go report card

Tags: go, gofmt

I have a Go project, where I wanted to generate a Go report card (https://goreportcard.com/)

One of the things that this report card is that it runs

```
 gofmt -s
```

On all files.

My repo contains around 25 Go files, the only flag that is raised is this one, on six files:

```
Line 1: warning: file is not gofmted with -s (gofmt)
```

I've been googling around on `gofmt`, but I really can't find what this actually means.

Here is an example of a file that raises the error:

```
package services

import (
    "github.com/heyjoakim/devops-21/models"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

var d = GetDBInstance()

// GetUserID returns user ID for username
func GetUserID(username string) (uint, error) {
    var user models.User
    getUserIDErr := d.db.First(&user, "username = ?", username).Error
    if getUserIDErr != nil {
        log.WithFields(log.Fields{
            "err": getUserIDErr,
            "username": username,
        }).Error("Error in GetUserID")
    }
    return user.UserID, getUserIDErr
}
```

and here is a file that does not raise the error:

```
package services

import (
    "strconv"

    "github.com/heyjoakim/devops-21/models"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

    func UpdateLatest(latest int) {
        var c models.Config
    
        err := d.db.First(&c, "key = ?", "latest").Error
        if err != nil {
            log.WithField("err", err).Error("Latest does not exist: DB err")
            c.ID = 0
            c.Key = "latest"
            c.Value = strconv.Itoa(latest)
            d.db.Create(&c)
        } else {
            err := d.db.Model(&models.Config{}).Where("key = ?", "latest").Update("Value", latest).Error
            if err != nil {
                log.WithField("err", err).Error("UpdateLatest: DB err")
            }
        }
    }
```

I really don't see why one raises some error on line 1, and the other doesn't?

What does this flag mean?

Comment: I think you may need to use `gofmt -s -w` to reformat the files.

Comment: It means what it says, run `gofmt -s`

Comment: Ok, so it says that I should run gofmt myself to actually see what the issues are?

Comment: when I run gofmt -s myfile.go on my files, it just outputs the file as it already looks. This is on the files that go report card raised the flag with.

Answer (score 1):

The command `gofmt -s myfile.go` prints the formatted file to stdout. The `-s` flag [applies simplifications](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/#hdr-The_simplify_command) to the formatted file.

Run `gofmt -s -d myfile.go` to view the differences between the original file and the formatted file.

Run `gofmt -s -w myfile.go` to update the file to the desired formatting.

Replace `myfile.go` with `.` to operate on all files in the directory.

The documentation for the gofmt command is [here](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/).

Your files are not formatted.  Run `gofmt -s -w .` in the directory to fix the files.